# Node.JS can't find Module inside Folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, blockchain, yarnpkg

I made a folder.  Then cloned code from GH into it.  so it's a folder inside my folder.  I run (node index.js) and it throws 'error, module not found.  What can I do differently?

```
`josh@Joshs-MBP random % node index.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/josh/Desktop/random/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}josh@Joshs-MBP random % `
```

Comment: There are still errors even once inside the correct folder. (Error: Cannot find module '/Users/josh/Desktop/random/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/sha1'
Require stack:
- /Users/josh/Desktop/random/hashlips_art_engine/src/main.js
- /Users/josh/Desktop/random/hashlips_art_engine/index.js)

Comment: Did you run `npm i` after cloning?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem -**

Running `node index.js` throws a module not found error.

**Solution -**

You need to change directory one directory level deeper.

You are currently in

`/Users/josh/Desktop/random/index.js`

You said you created a directory, then put a Github repo inside of that directory. That means you need to change directory into the Github repo still.

If you look at the error it shows that you are running `node index.js` inside of a directory on your Desktop.

Based on your description of putting a Github repo inside of a directory you created, you likely need to use `cd` to move into it.

**Solution -**

1. `cd repoName`
2. `ls` to verify `index.js` is in the current location.
3. When you see `index.js` in the output from `ls` type `node index.js`

Comment: Thanks for this!  I am still getting that error even inside the correct folder

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the code that is in index.js? Also, can you please tell me what the output is when you type `ls`? Also, do you have a package.json file? Will you share a link to the repo you are trying to use? I wonder if you actually should be typing `npm start` or `node main.js` or something different than `node index.js`. Clearly you are missing something. Please share more info so we can help.